# How to invoke JavaScript function when popup is open but not using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a popup defined in my parent page as a `PrimeFaces` `p:dialog`. It is opened using `PF('myDialog').show()`.

I also have a simple JS function that updates a `span` in the popup when a `textarea` within has an `onkeyup` event:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="comment" ... onkeyup="textCounter(this,'charactersRemaining',1000);"/>
```

That refreshes the `charactersRemaining` span on every text area change, meaning there is no remaining count shown before you've hit a key in the UI component.  However, I would like to trigger the `textCounter` JS function also when the popup loads for the first time so that it's always there.  I am asking for a way to do this as I am relatively new to JS.

In short, how do I say, run me `textCounter('commentField','charactersRemaining',1000);` when `myDialog` is opened?

Answer (score 1):

You could just call textCounter('commentField','charactersRemaining',1000); after PF('myDialog').show(); But if you want to you could trigger an event and consume it like this:

HTML
`<div id='myDialog'>This is my dialog</div>`

JAVASCRIPT

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
   (function ($) {
     $.each(['show', 'hide'], function (i, ev) {
       var el = $.fn[ev];
       $.fn[ev] = function () {
        this.trigger(ev);
        return el.apply(this, arguments);
       };
     });
   })(jQuery);



   $('#myDialog').on('show', function() {
     alert('Show event fired');
     textCounter('commentField','charactersRemaining',1000);
   });

   $('#myDialog').on('hide', function() {
     //Do something when myDialog is hidden
   });

   $('#myDialog').show();

});
```

Comment: unfortunately, your onShow function didn't work for me, even when the body was something as simple as `alert('HelloWorld');`

Comment: Wrap it in a `$(document).read(function{ ... });` The show event will fire whenever you call `$('#myDialog').show();`

Comment: can you change your answer to include that please ?